# ModMic with Creative USB soundcard

Tags: clipping, creative

I am currently running a *Creative X-Fi 5.1 Surround* external sound card via USB. The attached Antlion ModMic tends to clip when shouting, especially with VoIP software. So I lowered the input volume to 20%, which seems to be a reasonable value between my voice being loud enough and not clipping if speaking louder.

I am also rerouting the mics input to my headphones, which is a built-in feature of the soundcard. When clipping in VoIP/recording software occurs, the rerouted input is not clipping. Therefore I assume the input frequency range gets chopped of either by the OS or by the soundcards driver.

Is there any software to automatically decrease/increase the mics input volume like some VoIP (Discord, Skype) do, but system-wide?

Otherwise I am willing to buy a new sound card having these features:

- external (USB)
- speaker output (5.1 via audio jacks appreciated)
- headphone output/microphone input
- automatically switching between speakers and headphones by plugging/unplugging headphones
- good audio quality with automatic input leveling
- up to 200$

Any suggestions on the latter?

Comment: why the need for shouting? this question is probably going to be voted to be closed as off topic by someone in it's current wording. If you are trying to record the voice then using a compressor will automatically reduce higher input levels.

Comment: Sometimes gaming in online sessions will come along with a thrill of joy, which may lead to peaks in mic input. As I'm talking to my friends in realtime, there is no time for any compressors except it can work  in realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have heard of this: [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm)

It is a stand alone mixer with compressor. I'm not saying it is exactly what you need but you should look it up and see if it will work for you and watch some YouTube videos on it.